# Javascript - How to change src of iframe when video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

I would like to know how can I change the source of iframe automatically when video ends.
I am using this script to generate iframe and the function onPlayerStateChange to detect when the video ends. I basically need to change the videoID after the video finishes playing.
My JS:

```
    <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          width: '640',
          height: '390',
          videoId: 'gPDcwjJ8pLg',
          events: {
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {

        }
    }

</script>
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What immediately comes to mind is a playlist. Is there a reason that won't work in this situation? Could you give a bit more detail?

Comment: Well, I am working on a site where you can create your own playlists using embedded youtube video links. So i want to change video ID that I have in database when the video ends.

Comment: [Don't use Iframes.](http://jorgealbaladejo.com/2011/04/03/why-iframes-in-rich-web-applications-are-evil/) [They're "evil".](http://www.rwblackburn.com/iframe-evil/)

Also, Youtube provides it's own embed code for videos. If that doesn't work for you, you could probably rig something up with HTML5 `video` tags and JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this for several videos, you will need to generalize this. But I think this example (of an `index.html` file) should work:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            player.loadVideoById('iRXJXaLV0n4');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lukeschlangen/dbrhgdkb/1/